# Adapter in android which is using same overriden method

Tags: java, android

I am using switch case in which i am setting the adapter which is having same overridden method with duplicate code ,so i want to minimize it .

```
private void settingAdapter(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            adapter = new SongAdapter(getContext(), false, false)
            {
                @Override
                protected void onOverScrolled() {
                    super.onOverScrolled();
                    if(nextPageCount==null||nextPageCount.isEmpty())
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                    else {
                        int count = Integer.parseInt(nextPageCount);
                        getList(count);
                    }
                }
            };
            customList.setAdapter(adapter);
            break;
        case 1:
            adapter = new ArtistAdapter(getContext(), false, false, false){
                @Override
                protected void onOverScrolled() {
                    super.onOverScrolled();
                    if(nextPageCount==null||nextPageCount.isEmpty())
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                    else {
                        int count = Integer.parseInt(nextPageCount);
                        getList(count);
                    }
                }
            };
            customList.setAdapter(adapter);
            break;
        case 2:
            adapter = new AlbumAdapter(getContext(), false, false){
                @Override
                protected void onOverScrolled() {
                    super.onOverScrolled();
                    if(nextPageCount==null||nextPageCount.isEmpty())
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                    else {
                        int count = Integer.parseInt(nextPageCount);
                        getList(count);
                    }
                }
            };
            customList.setAdapter(adapter);
            break;
        case 3:
            adapter = new PlaylistAdapter(getContext(), false, false){
                @Override
                protected void onOverScrolled() {
                    super.onOverScrolled();
                    if(nextPageCount==null||nextPageCount.isEmpty())
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                    else {
                        int count = Integer.parseInt(nextPageCount);
                        getList(count);
                    }
                }
            };
            customList.setAdapter(adapter);
            break;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just make all your `Adapters` extend the same class?

```
public class BaseAdapter extends SomeAdapterOfYours {
    //... everything needed

    @Override
    protected void onOverScrolled() {
        super.onOverScrolled();
        if(nextPageCount==null||nextPageCount.isEmpty()){
            return;
        }
        else {
            int count = Integer.parseInt(nextPageCount);
            getList(count);
        }
    } 
}
```

And then your custom adapters:

```
public class ArtistAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
  //custom adapter stuff
}
```

```
public class SongAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
  //custom adapter stuff
}
```

and so on...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the same adapter the best strategy is create a `CustomAdapter` adapter in a class in a new file, import it in your Activity and create a instance every time you need it.

If you don't want to do it, you can control the case when you not setup the adapter and in the `default:` set it. You only need here one adapter.